# How to combine and sort key-value pair in Terraform

Tags: terraform

since the last update of the Logicmonitor provider in Terraform we're struggling with a sorting isse.

In LogicMonitor the properties of a device  are a name-value pair, and they are presented alfabetically by name. Also in API requests the result is alphabetical. So far nothing fancy.

But... We build our Cloud devices using a module. Calling the module we provide some LogicMonitor properties specially for this device, and a lot more are provided in the module itself.

In the module this looks like this:
`

```
custom_properties = concat([
    {
      name  = "host_fqdn"
      value = "${var.name}.${var.dns_domain}"
    },
    {
      name  = "ocid"
      value = oci_core_instance.server.id
    },
    {
      name  = "private_ip"
      value = oci_core_instance.server.private_ip
    },
    {
      name  = "snmp.version"
      value = "v2c"
    }
  ],
  var.logicmonitor_properties)
```

`

The first 4 properties are from the module and combined with anyting what is in var.logicmonitor_properties. On the creation of the device in LogicMonitor all properties are set in the order the are and no problem.

The issue arises when there is any update on a terraform file in this environment. Due to the fact the properties are presented in alphabetical order, Terraform is showing a lot of changes if finds (but which are in fact just a mixed due to sorting).

The big question is: How can I sort the complete list of properties bases on the "name".

Tried to work with maps, sort and several other functions and examples, but got nothing working on key-value pairs. Merging single key's works fine in a map, but how to deal with name/value pairs/

Answer (score 0):

I think you were on the right track with maps and sorting. Terraform maps do not preserve any explicit ordering themselves, and so whenever Terraform needs to iterate over the elements of a map in *some* explicit sequence it always do so by sorting the keys lexically (by Unicode codepoints) first.

Therefore one answer is to project this into a map and then project it back into a list of objects again. The projection back into list of objects will implicitly sort the map elements by their keys, which I think will get the effect you wanted.

```
variable "logicmonitor_properties" {
  type = list(object({
    name  = string
    value = string
  }))
}

locals {
  base_properties = tomap({
    host_fqdn      = "${var.name}.${var.dns_domain}"
    ocid           = oci_core_instance.server.id
    private_ip     = oci_core_instance.server.private_ip
    "snmp.version" = "v2c"
  })

  extra_properties = tomap({
    for prop in var.logicmonitor_properties : prop.name => prop.value
  })

  final_properties = merge(local.base_properties, local.extra_properties)

  # This final step will implicitly sort the final_properties
  # map elements by their keys.
  final_properties_list = tolist([
    for k, v in local.final_properties : {
      name  = k
      value = v
    }
  ])
}
```

With all of the above, `local.final_properties_list` should be similar to the `custom_properties` structure you showed in your question except that the elements of the list will be sorted by their names.

This solution assumes that the property names will be unique across both `base_properties` and `extra_properties`. If there are any colliding keys between both of those maps then the `merge` function will prefer the value from `extra_properties`, overriding the element of the same key from `base_properties`.

Comment: Thanks a lot, this does what I was hoping for. But unfortunately there is something weird happening "under the hood" which is no giving the expected result. Still properties shift around.

Will have to investigate further

Comment: If the provider itself is treating "properties" as an ordered list then there won't be any way to avoid it showing changes when you add and remove items in the middle of the list. It's ultimately up to the provider to decide how to interpret a particular configuration change, so if this provider is treating properties as ordered then it would require a change to the provider itself to avoid that.

Answer (score 0):

````
First, use the sort() function to sort the keys in alphabetical order:

sorted_keys = sort(keys(var.my_map))

Next, use the map() function to create a new map with the sorted keys and corresponding values:

sorted_map = map(sorted_keys, key => var.my_map[key])

Finally, you can use the jsonencode() function to print the sorted map in JSON format:

jsonencode(sorted_map)```
````